# How to stream live content to an HTML5 player

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming

So i have a server, that serves up livestreams, i can get the livestream through certain players like `JWPlayer`, even `VideoJS` but i want to be able to essentially look at what it would take to build my own player along these lines for playback. The livestream is going to the server via an `rtmp` string, and with JWPlayer im supplying it with an https based address, and it works, but im not sure whats going on behind the screen that allows this to happen with something like JWPlayer that i cant replicate with the HTML5, are you even able to replicate it? I can supply an https address to play video on demand from my servers just fine, but live content will not play at all in the HTML5 player.

Comment: Your `https://` address could be a lot of things.  You'll have to provide an example as to what format it's in.  HLS?  DASH?  Regular progressive streaming?

Comment: From what the streaming engine tells me when i use the JWPlayer to connect to the livestream its connecting via an rtmp url, though its formatted to look like an HLS http, as the streaming engine provides example urls to connect to the stream, and the HLS example, is formatted exactly that way. `https://{serverurl}/{wherethestreamislocated}/playlist.m3u8` but i also tried the streaming server's example of connecting via `MPEG_DASH` and that led to nothing. there's no errors or anything in the console, just nothing happens in the video player. and im wondering what more i can do..

Comment: Most browsers don't support HLS directly, but support it (and others) by way of the MediaSource Extensions.  You *could* do all of your own work to support HLS this way, but I wouldn't recommend it.  I'd recommend using HLS.js or similar.  A lot of cruft has built up over the years, so there are a lot of aspects you need to support if you wanted to start from scratch and be compatible with all the streams.